# How do I vertically center a fixed position background image that covers a container that is offset from the top of the viewport?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to vertically center a background-image that has a background-attachment of fixed on it and is 100px from the top. The background-size is set to cover so it is horizontally centering the background-image, but it is not centered vertically.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="header">
  <h1>Header</h1>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/LJubdtP.png">
</div>

<div class="crosshairs">
  <div class="xAxis"></div>
  <div class="yAxis"></div>
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre, a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code, del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp, small, strike, strong, /*sub, sup,*/ tt, var, b, u, i, center, dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li, fieldset, form, label, legend, table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td, article, aside, canvas, details, embed, figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary, time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

.header {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: tan;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/EvdsgOV.png');
    background-position: center 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 50;
}

.container img {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.crosshairs {
  width: 100%;
    margin-top: 100px;
    height: calc(100vh - 100px);
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}

.xAxis {
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.yAxis {
  width: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: red;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

My JS:

```
var backgroundImage = new Image();
backgroundImage.src = $('.container').css('background-image').replace(/"/g,"").replace(/url\(|\)$/ig, "");

backgroundImage.onload = function() {

  var object = $('.container');

  var bgImgWidth = this.width;
  var bgImgHeight = this.height;

  var imageRatio = bgImgWidth/bgImgHeight;
  var coverRatio = object.outerWidth()/object.outerHeight();

  if (imageRatio >= coverRatio) {
    /* The Height is our constant */
    var coverHeight = object.outerHeight();
    var scale = (coverHeight / bgImgHeight);
    var coverWidth = bgImgWidth * scale;
  } else {
    /* The Width is our constant */
    var coverWidth = object.outerWidth();
    var scale = (coverWidth / bgImgWidth);
    var coverHeight = bgImgHeight * scale;
  }
  var cover = coverWidth + 'px ' + coverHeight + 'px';
  //         alert('scale: ' + scale + ', width: ' + coverWidth + ', height: ' + coverHeight + ', cover property: ' + cover);

  var containerHeight = $('.container').height();
  var posFromTop = 100 + (containerHeight - coverHeight) * .5;
  console.log(coverHeight + ' coverHeight');
  console.log(containerHeight + ' containerHeight');
  console.log(posFromTop + ' posFromTop');
  $('.container').css('background-position', 'center ' + posFromTop + 'px');
};
```

I got it working if the viewport is less than 300px tall, but if it is taller than that, it does not give me the correct coverHeight value and does not work.

Here is my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/LxuxeL58/1/

Comment: This question is really confusing because we don't know what we're going for. However, is this it? https://jsfiddle.net/qusyuegm/2/  (works in Chrome)

Comment: OMG! It was so simple! Simply moving it down only half the height of the header works without any JS. Not if the height of the window gets too small, but that's okay for me.

Comment: Thank you! Thank you! So very much! I feel stupid now that I spent all day trying to figure this out. How do I mark your response as the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply moving it down only half the height of the header should work without any JS.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, it appears the error is within the .outerWidth() and .outerHeight() functions.

Another possible source of error could be in the use of the "this" keyword, as it always refers to the caller of the function which could (possibly) be the window object in this case.

I would suggest using Element.getBoundingClientRect() for width / height / position in calculations - but that's purely based on personal experience and not necessarily factual best-usage information.